Associativity of Convolutions
In Folland's real analysis textbook, there are the following propositions:

Assuming that all integrals in question exist, we have
$$
(f*g)*h=f*(g*h) $$

The proof is based on the Fubini's theorem.But I don't think this meets the conditions for using the Fubini's theorem.From the conditions of the original proposition, it can only be inferred that there exists a iterated integral:
$$
(f*g)*h(z)=\int \left( \int f(y)g(x-y) \, \mathrm{d}y  \right)h(z-x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
This reminds me of this famous counterexample:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}  \, \mathrm{d}x \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}} \, \mathrm{d}y\neq \int_{0}^{1}  \, \mathrm{d}y \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}} \, \mathrm{d}x 
$$
May I ask where I went wrong?
